# Angular: Bind to an @Input alias

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set an input alias in a directive following this [example](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#bind-to-an-input-alias)

```
  @Input('appAvatarColor') name: string;
```

The program is working, but I'm receiving this warning from TS Lint

> the directive input property should not be renamed

The directive selector is this

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAvatarColor]'
})
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Why is this considered a bad practice by default?

Comment: I suspect you have `"no-input-rename": true` rule in your `tslint.json` file

Comment: @yurzui yes. That's correct. I'm using the standard tslint.json generated by angular cli. My question is why is this considered a bad practice by default?

Comment: The accepted answer is now deprecated as we have `eslint` with Angular. I have added a new answer for `eslint`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can either turn off rule in `tslint.json`

```
"no-input-rename": false
```

or disable checking for only specific line like:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-input-rename
@Input('appAvatarColor') name: string;
```

> My question is why is this considered a bad practice by default?

- Two names for the same property (one private, one public) is inherently confusing.
- You should use an alias when the directive name is also an input property, and the directive name doesn't describe the property.

From https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#05-13

Comment: for the `"-input-rename`, I can agree that renames are confusing, after all the type of the field remains the same externally/internally. But for `@Output` there is also a `no-output-rename: true` by default. And I find this logic harder to comprehend, because unlike inputs, it's not symetrical. e.g. Externally it looks like an event:`(rowDeleted)="onRowDelete($event)"`, but internally it's not an event, but an `EventEmitter`. Naming it `rowDeleted` would make it look like a `boolean`. It make more sense to define it as `@Output('rowDeleted') private rowDeletedEventEmitter;`, right?

Comment: Nevertheless, this is a great answer :). But curious about your opinion regarding the `no-output-rename` as well.

Comment: For eslint v8.2.0 write
"no-input-rename": 0
Or you'll get Error: .eslintrc.json#overrides[0]:

Comment: Point 1: aliasing is typically done to solve inherently confusing binding names isnt it? Especially when forced to use a name eg.`@Input('cdkListItemTemplate') item: TemplateRef<any>;`

Answer (score 33):

You can implement it the following way :

```
@Input() appAvatarColor: string;
```

Comment: I believe you are not adding a alias here, you are only declaring your variable as 'appAvatarColor' instead of 'name'

Answer (score 5):

You should rename `@Input('appAvatarColor') name: string;` to something else for this to differ from the directive name. You can do `@Input('avatarColor') name: string;` and then simplify it by `@Input() avatarColor: string;`

Answer (score 4):

With new Angular version, tslint is gone and we need to use `eslint`. For Eslint, you need to modify `rules` inside the `.eslintrc.json` file and add `"@angular-eslint/no-input-rename"` as below.

Example:

```json
"rules": {
        // ..... some rules
        "@angular-eslint/no-input-rename": [
          "warn",
          { 
            "allowedNames": ["name"]
          }
        ],
       //.... more rules
     }
```

Comment: Thank you @Shashank!
Also `"@angular-eslint/no-output-rename": "warn"`

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it should be the following:

```
@Input() appAvatarColor: string;
```