# Bind to @Input alias where directive is kebab-case

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint

I am attempting to use kebab-case in my directive and camelCase as my alias. Something like

**my-component.html**

```html
<my-component [my-input]='myParentInput'></my-component>
```

**my-html-component.ts**

```typescrpt
export MyComponent {
  @Input('my-input') myInput;
}
```

This works, but throws error on linting

> error  In the class MyComponent, the directive input property `myInput` should not be renamed  `@angular-eslint/no-input-rename`

On researching I came across this discussion [Angular: Bind to an @Input alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033676/angular-bind-to-an-input-alias). Generally aliasing is discouraged with the reason

> Avoid *input* and *output* aliases except when it serves an important purpose.
> **Why?** Two names for the same property (one private, one public) is inherently confusing.

The above reason will not apply as no property will be created with the name 'my-input'

Now in the above approach I could have used the below approach and avoid the error

**my-component.html**

```html
<my-component [myInput]='myParentInput'></my-component>
```

**my-html-component.ts**

```typescrpt
export MyComponent {
  @Input myInput;
}
```

I wouldn't want to use this approach, Personal preference (`Vue` background). So I have one option to disable the warning as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033976/13680115

The problem with this approach is that it will disable the rule completely from my project and If I am to disable for specific lines, I will end up with quite a number of disables

Is there a way one can disable the rule for kebab-case @Input directives while throw error for camelCase @Inputs ?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108039/typescript-error-while-using-input/47108502

Comment: @igor_c thanks for the reference but the approach being mentioned here I have highlighted in my question